Cylinder rolling on a triangle - Mechanics

A cylinder is on the top of a triangular block. The block is on the ground and can translate horizontally (no frinction). The cylinder can roll on the inclined side of the triangular block (without sliding). Cylinder mass is $m_c$, block mass is $m_b$, the cylinder radius is $R$, and the inclined side of the block form an angle wrt the horizontal which is assumed known.
The whole system is subject to the gravitational force and the reaction of the ground.
How is moving the center of mass of the whole system? And the motion of the cylinder and the block wrt a reference frame attached to the center of mass?

I should use a Lagrangian mechanics approach.
